# is it possible to use GCP without firebase?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

This is insane, can't find anything on this.
Can I use Google Cloud Platform for google sign in in my android app without firebase?

Comment: The [Google Sign-In for Android guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) says nothing about Firebase. What makes you think you have to use Firebase?

Comment: If there are no documentation in wich case did you encountered this problem?

Comment: @ianhanniballake The problem is that google does not give you a way (Or is hiding it very well) to generate google-services.json file for your project.

Comment: @MihailGutan - what makes you think you need a `google-services.json` file for Google Sign-In? It sounds like you aren't following the same guide I linked to (which makes no mention of it being necessary).

Comment: @ianhanniballake from this gradle error `File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. `

Comment: You don't need the Google Services plugin for Google Sign In.

Comment: That would be great, but why does google plugin complain about the missing file then?